# Fastest way to use memory mapped files to read packfiles?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, memory-mapped-files

I have a C++ application that is designed solely for 64-bit systems. Currently I am working on the Windows implementation of the packfile system. The packfiles themselves incorporate a few thousand individually compressed files into them. The access pattern is expected to be multiple threads accessing different files at different times, but those individual files are (almost) always accessed sequentially. The files are expected to remain memory mapped for the duration of the program, accessed sporadically but often in short bursts where many files are accessed at once.

What is the best way to maximize the ability of Windows to perform read-ahead optimizations in this case?

My concern with a single file mapping is that the access is then not really sequential, but is basically entirely random with local sequentiality. I see two options, but I don't know which is better, or if another option is preferred:

1. Create a new file handle to the packfile for each subfile I wish to memory map, then CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile for each.
2. Create a single file handle to the packfile, and then create a unique file mapping for each subfile.

My gut feeling is that #1 will let Windows do the best job, but I worry about having tons of file handles allocated. Thoughts?